# Local homeomorphisms: terminology

Tags: general-topology, terminology, sheaf-theory

Let $(E,\pi,X)$ be a local homeomorphism, so for any $x\in E$ there is an open set $U\ni x$ such that $\pi|U$ maps $U$ homeomorphically onto $\pi[U]\subseteq X$, and $\pi[U]$ is open in $X$.

Is there a standard terminology for such open sets $U$? "Even" $U$? "Flat" $U$? "Simple" $U$? "Schlicht" $U$?

I'm particularly interested in the context where $(E,\pi,X)$ is the etale space of a sheaf.

Comment: I suggest *$X$-neighborhood*.

Comment: But is this standard terminology in the literature? As far as suggestions go, I'd want something independent of the letters chosen, so that, e.g., you could write "Given a flat open set for a local homeomorphism..." and not have to name the base space.

Comment: No, this is just something I came up with. I was inspired by *Euclidean neighborhood* which are homeomorphic to open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, and that wording is used in a *manifold*, which is a space $M$ with a local homeomorphism to $\Bbb R^n$. So if we replace $\Bbb R^n$ with a space $X$, replacing *Euclidean neighborhood* by $X$-*neighborhood* seems natural.

Answer (score 0):

I would provocatively call it an *étale neighbourhood* of $x$ in $X$ over $E$. ;-) As it is the standard terminology in the analogue case in algebraic geometry, or differential/complex analytic geometry...

Comment: Is this terminology standard?

Comment: In the contexts I mentioned, it damn is, yes ! ;-) So I'd go for the same terminoly in your case.

Comment: But the etale neighborhood belongs to the base space, is that right? I'm wondering about a term for the open set in the etale space that "evenly covers" its image.

Comment: Look at this : http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/etale+map